# Printing and Sorting txt file in C

Tags: c

I want to make a program which is able to read, sort (alphabetically and numerically), and print: country name, GDP, and population in a table format. I am having trouble in having the program to read all my txt file contents. How do I fix this? And are there any tips on sorting the txt file alphabetically and/or numerically? Thank you

The header data:

```
typedef struct countrydata{
     char countries[50];
     float gdp;
     float population;
}Country;
```

The program I've written so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <countrydata.h>


int main(void){
     Country countries[1000];
     char dateiname[1000];
     int i, j;
     char string[1000];
     i=1;
     printf("Geben Sie den Dateiname ein: ");
     scanf("%s", &dateiname);
     FILE *fp;
     fp = fopen(dateiname , "r");
     if(fp == NULL){
         printf("Error in opening file");
         return -1;
     }
     while(1){
         fgets(string,1000,fp);
         strcpy(countries[i].countries, strtok(string,";"));
         countries[i].gdp = atof(strtok(NULL,";"));
         countries[i].population = atof(strtok(NULL,";"));
    
         printf("%i %-18s %-15.2f %-12f\n", i, countries[i].countries, countries[i].gdp, countries[i].population);
    
         if(feof(fp)){
             fclose(fp);
             break;
         }
         i++;
     }
     return 0;
 }
```

A snippet of the .txt data:

```
country;gdp;population
Afghanistan;19101.35;38041754
Albania;15278.08;2880917
Algeria;169988.24;43053054
```

Comment: Check the returned value from `fgets()` before using it.  That then makes the `feof()` test pointless.

Comment: Your `while` loop construction isn't a proper way to read until EOF. The `feof(fp)` is true *after* an attempt to read past the end of file. You should be looking at the return value of `fgets`. Can you clarify what symptom you have indicating that you are having trouble reading all of your data? Tip on sorting: use `qsort`.

Comment: You start `i` at 1; that means you don’t use the first element of the array.  That’ll give trouble sooner or later.

Comment: The loop should be `for (int i = 0; fgets(string, sizeof string, fp) != NULL; i++)`. Everything after the `printf` in the loop should be deleted (you should never use `feof()`). And the `fclose()` should be after the loop.

Comment: You should also put a `fgets(string, sizeof string, fp)` before the loop to read (and ignore) the first line of the file.